# Filtering undefined elements out of an array

Tags: typescript

I have some code that filters an array with type `(Suggestion|undefined)[]` into an array with type `Suggestion[]`, but I feel it does so very inelegantly:

```
const optionsProvider: AutocompletionProvider = () => {
    const results: (Suggestion|undefined)[] = flagDescriptions.map(descriptions => {
        let shortFlagWithArgument = descriptions[0].match(/^ *-(\w) (\w*)$/);
        let shortFlagWithoutArgument = descriptions[0].match(/^ *-(\w) *(.*)$/);
        if (shortFlagWithArgument) {
            const flag = shortFlagWithArgument[1];
            const argument = shortFlagWithArgument[2];
            const description = combineManPageLines(descriptions.slice(1));

            return new Suggestion({
                value: `-${flag}`,
                style: styles.option,
                description,
                displayValue: `-${flag} ${argument}`,
            });
        } else if (shortFlagWithoutArgument) {
            const flag = shortFlagWithoutArgument[1];
            const description = combineManPageLines([shortFlagWithoutArgument[2], ...descriptions.slice(1)]);

            return new Suggestion({
                value: `-${flag}`,
                style: styles.option,
                description,
            });
        }
    });
    const filteredResults: Suggestion[] = [];
    results.forEach(result => {
        if (result) {
            filteredResults.push(result);
        }
    });
    return filteredResults;
};
```

In straight JS, this would just be `array.filter(element => element !== undefined)` but the best working solution I could come up with in TypeScript was to `push` the defined elements into a separate array within a `forEach`.

For context:

```
type AutocompletionProvider = (context: AutocompletionContext) => Suggestion[] | Promise<Suggestion[]>;
```

Original PR: https://github.com/shockone/black-screen/pull/623/files

Comment: We allow links in questions, but the code you wish to be reviewed must be in the question body itself.

Comment: Sorry @DanPantry I didn't realize. Fixed.

Comment: I don't understand the point of the type `(Suggestion|undefined)[]` in the first place. It is ok to put `undefined` into a `Suggestion[]`, so why not change the type to be simply `Suggestion[]` throughout?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To be using strict null checks, you must be on `"typescript": "^2.0.0"`. Thus, my example will be using this version of typescript with `"compilerOptions":{"strictNullChecks": true}`.

It does seem that the `filter` solution is the most elegant solution to the titular question. Sadly, it seems that the typescript static analysis is unable to track this behavior:

```typescript
const source: (string|undefined)[] = ["one", "two", "three", undefined, "five"]
const filtered: string[] = source.filter(element => element !== undefined)
//  [ts]
//    Type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
//      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
//        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

This seems to be the case because of the declaration of the `filter` method:

```typescript
/** Returns the elements of an array that meet the condition specified in a callback function. */
(method) Array<string | undefined>.filter(callbackfn: (value: string | undefined, index: number, array: (string | undefined)[]) => any, thisArg?: any): (string | undefined)[]
```

In this case, our own type logic beats out the compiler's. It's these cases that is the reason that [Type Assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19461479/3019990) is part of the language spec. Thus:

```typescript
const source: (string|undefined)[] = ["one", "two", "three", undefined, "five"]
const filtered: string[] = source.filter(element => element !== undefined) as string[]
```

This transpiles exactly as you would expect -- in this case, transpiling is as simple as just removing the type information. If you need to convince the language to convert two unrelated types, you need to step through any to tell the compiler to back off: `object as any as string`.

---

Now, looking at the rest of the code:

`shortFlagWithArgument` and `shortFlagWithoutArgument` can be `const`s, as you do not mutate their values.

Personally, I would add an explicit final `return` to the `flagDescriptions.map` operation. This makes explicit why the `undefined` needs to be in the results array in the first place.

The regex patterns seem good candidates for refactoring into a reusable constant. Depending on your project ecosystem, however, it may be better just to leave them inlined.

Answer (score 22):

Typescript 1.6 introduced user defined type guards that are a function whose return type is a boolean that is cast as a type predicate. To define a simple `isString` type guard (note the `X is string` return type), use syntax like below:

```
function isString(str: string | undefined): str is string { return str !== undefined }
```

or as a lambda with a slightly different check:

```
const isString = (str: string | undefined): str is string => !!str
```

Passing a type guard function as the array `filter` callback predicate function will both filter the array and allow Typescript to correctly infer the return type. To expand on the accepted answer's example:

```
const source: (string|undefined)[] = ["one", "two", "three", undefined, "five"]
const filtered: string[] = source.filter( isString )
```

The `isString` lambda can also be expanded inline

```
const filtered: string[] = source.filter( (str: string | undefined): str is string => !!str )
```

This approach allows the Typescript compiler to infer types instead of explicit type casting. Yes, the type inference is dependent on the predicate function being correctly defined. But an incorrect predicate will give the wrong answer when filtering with a type cast too.

Comment: This is a good use of new language features, and I learned something! +1

Answer (score 14):

Building on [@RichardJohnson's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/184004/120114): why not write one function that can filter *any* array of possibly-undefined values? Let's make it generic.

```
export function filterUndef<T>(ts: (T | undefined)[]): T[] {
  return ts.filter((t: T | undefined): t is T => !!t)
}
```

This simplifies your filter call, too:

```
const nums = [20, 44, undefined]
const numsSafe = filterUndef(ages)
```

The typescript compiler can even use type inference to figure out `numsSafe` is `number[]`. Just define this function once, and reuse it whenever you want to strip the `undefined`s from an array in a typesafe way.

Comment: I added a link to the answer - I presume you meant Richard's answer but if I got that wrong then please updated it appropriately.

Comment: Using `!!t` as the filter condition will cause `0` values to be unexpectedly filtered out of the array. I used `t !== undefined` instead.